# Simple calculator in C, Only the multiplication operator doesn't work

Tags: c

I've started to learn C and in the chapter on "user input" there is an example calculator simply using command-line arguments. When I wrote and compiled it on my own machine, all the operators (-, +, /) except the multiplication (*) operator worked. When trying to multiply it just displays the command prompt on a new line. Any reason for this? Could the example be wrong? Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int arg1, arg2;
  if (argc == 4)
  {
    sscanf (argv[1], "%d", &arg1);
    sscanf (argv[3], "%d", &arg2);
    if (*argv[2] == '+') printf ("%d\n", arg1 + arg2);
    if (*argv[2] == '-') printf ("%d\n", arg1 - arg2);
    if (*argv[2] == '*') printf ("%d\n", arg1 * arg2);
    if (*argv[2] == '/') printf ("%d\n", arg1 / arg2);
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, this is a Windows versus Linux problem. Use `./a.out 2 \* 3` to prevent the `*` being expanded to all the files in the current directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use \ before * if you are using a Unix Shell otherwise The shell will understand it as a wild card character.

```
$ ./yourapp 1 \* 1
1
```

good luck and happy coding :)